# Spring .properties files purpose

Tags: java, spring

I read @yorkw answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874017/controlling-a-project-with-maven-and-spring-how-to-set-spring-config-file-using) topic. He said:

> The purpose of .properties file is to provide the capability of
>   configuring database connections at application runtime (for web
>   application, usually require restarting application container/server
>   after .properties file changes).

*The question is if we can change properties on the fly without restarting container/server? Provide me an example please (I ask because in my demo it doesn't work, means value isn't changed).*

I mean if we have some kind of admin tool than we can move all our configured settings to .properties files and change them via that admin tool.

Comment: It's a file. So yes. Only I'll imagine you'll need to write the admin tool.

Comment: @christopher thanks. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Check out `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Comment: ^ Yeah check out that mouthful.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, but if don't use Bundle and MessageSource in my application. I just want to change color theme of my site  at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring property files are designed to change the Spring Config of an application. The spring config is read when the spring container is initialised - this will form part of the application startup.

If a change is made to one of the spring config files (includes the *.properties files) the spring container would need to be reloaded to pick up the change.

Properties put into spring properties files should typically be properties that are tied to the life cycle of the application - i.e. the kind of properties that when changed require an application/spring container re-initialised - things like the database url/config etc.

So values that you want to change at runtime without requiring a restart of the application are not good candidates for placement in a spring properties file.

Comment: provide a few examples when we use .properties files please