# How to force Eclipse to use maven for automatic build

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat7

I am using Eclipse ,Spring,tomcat server,maven.
I need to pass some parameters when i build the project with maven.Everything works fine when i do that using command line or when i right click on POM.xml and run it making run configuration changes in eclipse.

But as soon as i start my tomcat it is not able to find the value i want to pass in the parameter and it gives an exception

: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/properties/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties]

here ${spring.profiles.active} should be replaced the the argument value.

So eclipse is not using maven with argument to build and deploy on the server automatically.

Comment: Have a look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874017/controlling-a-project-with-maven-and-spring-how-to-set-spring-config-file-using

Comment: Hi, My question is that I am able to get the argument that i am passing from maven and every this is fine if i deploy the jar on my tomcat by manually putting it into webapps folder. but when i use the tomcat that i haved added in eclipse and eclipse is building the war for me then i am not able to get the maven arguments.So, is there some way to force eclipse to use the maven configuration to build the war.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the required maven plugins (especially `maven-eclipse-plugin`) in the `pom.xml` for compiling the code and use the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the project's base directory. This will do the required stuff to create a maven project in eclipse.

Comment: i already have the below entry in my POm<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
     <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
     <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
     <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>   tried using  mvn eclipse:eclipse in the bse DIR but still the same issue. The variable is not replaced with the value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated subject where many things can go wrong. You need to be very explicit of how you are running tomcat. Are you using wtp? WTP would be the panel that says "Servers". Is this spring boot? Do have the m2eclipse wtp plugin installed (its very hidden and not easy to find)?

One easier way to get this right is just use springs version of eclipse.